# Can't access localhost using server's public IP

Tags: networking, apache-http-server

I am trying to install an Apache Server in my Ubuntu 18.04 and I get the public IP address through different ways (curl, http://www.see-my-ip.com/,...).

However, when I try to access Apache configuration page using this IP, a user and a password is asked, I suppose that the one for the router.[see screenshot on the link (https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZkeN.gif).

I am connected either to a public network or to my Android phone's data network, having the same problem in both of them.

Any clues of what can I do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, set-up portforwarding on your DSL router.

But first: unless you have a very special reason for administrating your DSL router from the Internet: **TURN THAT OFF**. It is in shouting capitals, because this is a serious security issue. Only allow adinistration of the DSL router from the inside network.

Also, if your router listens to the port, you will not be able to forward that port to your server.

How to set-up port forwarding depends on the router.  For some DSL routers, it is in the menu as forwarding, for others you will have to dig in the advanced menu.  You will need to consult the manual for the DSL router.

What portforwarding does is send the packets it receives to the local server and translate the public IP to a local IP and back.

or example, the following network:

```
+------+ a.b.c.d   (-----)   e.f.g.h+------+10.1.1.1      10.1.1.2+------+
|client|----------(Internet)--------|router|----------------------|apache|
+------+            (-----)         +------+                      +------+
```

Your portforwarding rule will be

- outside IP address e.f.g.h
- outside port:80

to

- inside IP 10.1.1.2
- inside port 80

When the client sends a packet (from a.b.c.d:high_port to e.f.g.h:80) the router will translate the packet into (from a.b.c.d:high_port to 10.1.1.2:80), as the rule has defined, and send it to Apache. When Apache gives a reply, (from 10.1.1.2:80 to a.b.c.d:high_port), the router will translate back to (from e.f.g.h:80 to a.b.c.d:high_port) and send it to the client. That is in a nutshell how portforwarding works.

Comment: I can't access the router when I am connected to a public network (e.g. library, etc). In the case of my Android phone's data network, how can I know the DSL user and password?